# composer require laravel/ui --dev

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-ui

I'm new to Laravel and have been trying to set up this code and composer give me  following error

When I run the command:`composer require laravel/ui --dev`

> [InvalidArgumentException] Package laravel/ui at version has a PHP
>   requirement incompatible with your PHP version (5.6.38)
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed]
>   [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts]
>   [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies]
>   [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
>   [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Does anyone know how to fix this one?

**NOTE : My PHP Version is : 7.4.3 !

Comment: Yes you need `PHP 7.2` check laravel documentation.

Comment: PHP 5.6, 7 and 7.1 are end of life. You should not be using them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be what the error message says:

> Package laravel/ui at version has a PHP requirement incompatible with
>   your PHP version (5.6.38)

**Solution**: Update your PHP with the latest version

---

Apart from this, PHP version (5.6.38) has been [unsupported](http://php.net/eol.php) for 11 months ago

Comment: I use wamp server work with php 7.2.10 but i have the same error

Comment: @asad Sorry, but your error should be resolved with this solution.

Comment: restart your command prompt @asad I assume you have not restarted your command prompt after upgrading the PHP version, Still error i think is old error